# File reading program has... black-screen issue

Tags: c++, readfile

OK, so I'm having a little trouble with this. This IS for homework, specifically my C++ Programming I final, but I'm having what I assume to be a logic flaw. All it's supposed to do at this time is read in information from a specified file, store it in a pair of parallel 2-dimensional arrays (one for string data, the other for numerical data), and then print it to the screen. Nothing else has been put in yet, and isn't required until the second half of the project.

When I run the code, it loads the console window, and then sits there blank. If someone could be so kind as to direct me to the general vicinity of the issue, I'd be grateful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void readFile(int numericData[80] [4], string textData[80] [7]);
void printData(int numericData[80] [4], string textData[80] [7]);

int main()
{
    string trash;
    string textData [80] [7];
    /* columns: 0 = name 1 = Weakness 2 = drops
    3 = stealables 4 = poach item
    5 = appearnce type 6 = location */

    int numericData [80] [4];
    // columns: 0 = HP 1 = XP 2 = LP 3 = diff rank
    // used 2 multi-dimensional parallel arrays to avoid 10 parallel arrays

    readFile(numericData, textData);
    printData(numericData, textData);

    return 0;
}

void readFile(int numericData[80] [4], string textData[80] [7])
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("filename");

    string trash;
    string rankConverter;
    for (int i = 0; i < 169; i++)
    {
        getline(inputFile, trash);
    }
    //throws out first 173 trash lines, until first usale line.


    for (int rareReader = 0; rareReader < 80; rareReader++)
    {
        // edited for brevity. this section reads each individual component
        // of the file and inserts them into the appropriate array section.

        do
        {
            getline(inputFile, trash);
        }
        while (trash != "end-entry marker");
        // throws away the rest of each entry as trash
    }
    //felt it relevant to mention that the following close command is before all
    //lines of the file have been read and thrown out. not sure if relevant.
    inputFile.close();
}



void printData(int numericData[80] [4], string textData[80] [7])
{
    cout << setw(10) << "Name";
    cout << setw(10) << "HP";
    cout << setw(10) << "XP";
    cout << setw(10) << "LP";
    cout << setw(6) << "Rank";
    cout << setw(10) << "Weakness";
    cout << setw(10) << "Sprite";
    cout << setw(10) << "Poach" << endl;
        cout << setw(20) << "Drop";
    cout << setw(20) << "Steals";
    cout << setw(20) << "Location";



    for (int printCount = 0; printCount < 80; printCount++)
    {
        cout << setw(10) << textData[printCount][0];
        cout << setw(10) << numericData[printCount][0];
        cout << setw(10) << numericData[printCount][1];
        cout << setw(10) << numericData[printCount][2];
        cout << setw(6) << numericData[printCount][3];
        cout << setw(10) << textData[printCount][1];
        cout << setw(10) << textData[printCount][5];
        cout << setw(10) << textData[printCount][4] << endl;
        cout << setw(20) << textData[printCount][2];
        cout << setw(20) << textData[printCount][3];
        cout << setw(20) << textData[printCount][6];
        /* columns: 0 = name 1 = Weakness 2 = drops
        3 = stealables 4 = poach item
        5 = appearnce type 6 = location */
        //copy of note for convenience in reading
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging this? Also show us a short sample of your input. Just from my guts, you're not checking `inputFile.open()` for errors, your `do {} while();` might run forever because of an `istream` with failbit set.

Comment: this likely (in fact definitely) isn't the cause of your error, but i don't see you populating your `numericData` and `textData` matrices anywhere in the program, yet you read from them in the`printData` function. this will likely case your `printData` function to output blank lines/garbage values.

Comment: hate to admit it, but you're half right g-makulik. after takng the "caveman debugging" method (my initial population loop iterates 80 times, so adding a test print to the end of it was WAY faster than stepping though the debugger), i discovered that one of the areas doesn't have all the lines.

Comment: Glad to help! Not to mention @NickWeedon's contribution.

Answer (score 1):

The program is most likely hanging somewhere. Try printing to the screen at the start of the program. If that works then keep adding 'cout' calls to print more debug messages until you find the point where the program is hanging. This is a debugging method that you will use time and time again. Sometimes referred to as 'cave man' debugging since the more advanced alternative is to attach a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: This really isn't an answer - in that it doesn't solve his problem. Suggesting that the OP do debugging should be a comment.

Comment: I'm still using this 'caveman' (+1 for the term :) ) a lot. Because it's really the quickest way to hunt down the location of a bug.

Comment: Jonathon: Oh, sorry, won't do that again. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart In principle you're right, but it will at least help the OP narrowing down his question. I'm pragmatic about such things sometimes.

Comment: I agree guys, I'm just saying it should be a comment, not an answer. I understand Nick probably can't comment yet with only 9 rep. He should just wait then, by posting "good" questions and answers, until he can comment.

Comment: *shrugs* comment or answer, it's an idea i didn't have. I'll take a pock shot at it, be back when i'm done.

Comment: So, the "caveman" debugging WAS the answer, since the other option was to step through 80 iterations of my read-in code... last entry in my file was done differently to mark end of stuff. Thanks, nick!